# Format locale-appropriate day and month without year

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there a way to format a locale-appropriate day and month *without* a year via Win32 (in C++)? For example, I would like to see 10/31 for the US locale and 31/10 for the UK locale. I know that `GetDateFormat` accepts a format string, but then the day and month are locked into whatever positions I specify in the format string, which will not be appropriate for all locales.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GetLocaleInfo` to query the user's date format in order to build your own format string.

`LOCALE_IDATE` returns a value indicating the relative order of day and month, alternatively `LOCALE_SSHORTDATE` returns the short date format string. In the latter case you would need to parse this yourself to work out the relative order.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! I hit upon the idea of using GetLocaleInfo to query the format moments before I saw your answer, so good to know I seem to barking up the right tree with this. Good to know about LOCALE_IDATE, too.